# web part wsp package including application page

Tags: visual-studio-2010, powershell, sharepoint-2010, web-parts, applicationpage

Good day,
 i am having trouble deploying a web part and application page in a wsp package.

I have developed a custom web part and the solution has a application page. When using Visual studio to deploy the solution, both are deployed, but then i package it and try deploy it using powershell the application page doesnt show up in the /_layouts page.

Is there some property i have to set so the application page can be deployed or am i missing something?!

Where do i have to specify that the application page should be included in the wsp?

Comment: have you added a mapped folder to _layouts ??

Comment: yes it has been mapped.. I think the problem is that in my development i used the main site and in testing its on a subsite..